# Raspberry Pi 4でUbuntu Serverを動かしたいのですが、OSを書き込んだMicroSDの/boot/firmware/usercfg.txtというファイルがありません。

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

こんばんは。お世話になります。
Raspberry Pi 4でUbuntu Serverを動かしたいのですが、
OSを書き込んだMicroSDの`/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`というファイルがありません。

Qiitaの[Raspberry Pi 4 4GBモデルでUbuntu Server 19.10を起動](https://qiita.com/shimejifarm/items/2347f744f228e8f3fc71)という記事を参考にさせて頂いてます。

この記事の手順「3.OSイメージの書き換え」には`/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`の最後に`total_mem = 2048`と追加しなければならないそうなのですが、そもそも`/boot/firmware/`の下に`usercfg.txt`が存在しないのです。

この場合は、`usercfg.txt`を自分で追加してもよいのでしょうか？
ご教授願います。

Comment: まずは実際の環境で試してどうなるかを確認してみましょう。そのファイルが無いとOSは起動しませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usercfg.txtは作成するんですよ
そうしたら起動しました